# Devise authentication: log out and redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, logout

Is there a way to write Rails method which will log out and redirect to custom page? I'm using Devise authentication gem.

I do not want that ALL logouts will be followed by this redirect, but only in the place where this method is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the conditions that you have in order to redirect to one place or to another, but here is what I do in my application to redirect differently depending on the role of my user:

Add this as a private method in your **ApplicationController**:

```
  private 

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    # If it's admin 
     if is_admin?(current_user)
        admin_path
    # Otherwise
     else
        root_path
     end
  end
```

Basically, you need to find which condition you need to apply in the [after_sign_out_path](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_out_path_for-instance_method) and return the path accordingly to that condition.  Notice that you get a symbol with the scope, and therefore you can use that to choose your returned path for the redirect.

Comment: So, it seems, I should define a set of custom flags, each for every location. As such flag I could set some global variable with destination path.

Comment: You only answered half the question.

Comment: Cyle Hunter feel free to make a better answer :)